# How can I get this program to also print the first entry in the list too?

Tags: java, sql, database

I can't display the first entry from my query that returns multiple answers.  For example, a search with a result set of five will return the second to fifth and miss the first entry.  If I search for something that has one entry as output it doesn't return anything but just hangs because it is the first and only entry in the database.  When I debug it and search for something that I know has only one entry in the DB, it goes to line 12 then 15 then 25.  How can I modify the loop to include the first entry to be printed also?

CODE:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs;
    String comparex = jTextField2.getText().trim().toUpperCase();// puts the textfield into a string object
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM BASTIMP where DETAILS like '%"+comparex+"%'"
    ); //paradox equivalent '..comparex..'
    String amount;
    String date;
    String attached = "";

    if (rs.next()) // **Line 12**
    {

    }else {
        DisplayAreaX.setText("ENTER VALID VENDOR");
    }  
    while (rs.next()) { // **Line 15**
        String details = rs.getString("DETAILS"); //get results from DETAILS
        date = rs.getString ("DATE PAID");        //CORRECT?
        amount = rs.getString ("AMOUNT BANK");
        attached = attached + details +":"+ '\n'+ "Date " +date+ " / "+
            "Amount £"+ amount+ '\n'; // - ADDS MULTIPLE ENTRIES ON OUTPUT OF jList!
        DisplayAreaX.setText(attached);
        System.out.println(details+":"+ '\n'+ "Date "+date+ " / "+
            "Amount £"+ amount+ '\n');
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: " + cE.toString());
} // **Line 25**
```

Thanks

Comment: Done, at least partially. Could do with some more cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling rs.next() twice before accessing the results. I would say that there are two options, first replace the while with a do...while loop, or remove the if/else statement and keep track of the results in a counter, and at the end check if the counter is 0 and display the message then.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  It works perfectly when I remove the if/else statement.  But how could the code display 'invalid vendor' when wrong data is entered? Could you ammend the code?

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the logic to:

```
int recordCount = 0;

while (rs.next()) 
{
  recordCount ++;
  String details = rs.getString("DETAILS"); //get results from DETAILS
  date = rs.getString ("DATE PAID");        //CORRECT?
  amount = rs.getString ("AMOUNT BANK");
  attached = attached + details +":"+ '\n'+ "Date " +date+ " / "+  "Amount £"+ amount+ '\n'; // - ADDS MULTIPLE ENTRIES ON OUTPUT OF jList!
  DisplayAreaX.setText(attached);
  System.out.println(details+":"+ '\n'+ "Date "+date+ " / "+  "Amount £"+ amount+ '\n');
}

if (recordCount == 0) 
{
   DisplayAreaX.setText("ENTER VALID VENDOR");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
only problem when I try I get the bug of 'incompatable types boolean and int'.  Also operator ++ can't be applied to boolean.

Comment: I think the intention was to make recordCount an int.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [do-while](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement instead while :-)